# Basis of the solutions of a linear differental equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

As the title says what is the basis of the solutions of a linear differential equation. Is there even one?

What does "homogeneous" and "inhomogeneous" mean relating to linear differential equations? And has this any influence related to the former question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A linear differential equation is an equation of the form $Lu(x)=f(x)$, where $L$ is a linear differential operator (e.g., $Lu=2u^\prime + u^{\prime\prime}$).

If $f=0$, we say the differential equation is *homogeneous*. Otherwise, we say is *inhomogeneous*.

If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are solutions of $Lu=0$, then so too is $v_1+cv_2$ for any scalar $c$. To see this, use the linearity of $L$ to obtain $$L(v_1+cv_2)=Lv_1+cLv_2=0.$$ In other words, the set of solutions $V$ is a vector space.

By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)), a basis for $V$ is just a set $B=\{v_i\}$ of linearly independent solutions such that any solution $v \in V$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors in $B$ (i.e., $v=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i b_i$).

Comment: Your first sentence is a bit confusing. You should write that this is just an example. Actually what I wanted to know is: As we know many hom. lin. dif. eq. can be solved using $x(t)=e^{λt}$ are there any other solutions? Do we know the vector space of all solutions of hom. lin. dif. eq., or isn't it that simple? If there is such a vector space is it the same as for inhomgeneous ones too?

Comment: $t \mapsto \mapsto e^{\lambda t}$ is a solution of the equation $x^\prime(t) = \lambda x(t)$. As I said above, so too is $t \mapsto ce^{\lambda t}$ for any constant $c$. In this case, these are all the solutions (i.e., the solution set is a 1-dimensional vector space), but this is not the case for all hom. lin. diff. eq.! (consider second order ODEs) I'm not sure I understand your second question. As for your last question, the solution set for inhom. eq. do not form a vector space.

Comment: As for your last question, the solution set for inhom. eq. do not form a vector space. Exactly what I wanted to know! Thought so...
Does the solution set of hom. lin. diff. eq form a vector space?

Comment: @Aresloom: yes, the solution set of hom. lin. diff. eq forms a vector space; we already addressed this. I recommend learning the definition of a vector space, the span of a subset of a vector space, and basis. You should then be able to follow the arguments above. Also, please consider up-voting and/or accepting answers to your questions that are helpful (even if you don't think mine is, it's good policy for future answers ad will make more people willing to answer your future questions).